# PHP loop thru hex numbers from a form POST always gives the first number as 0. why?

Tags: php, loops, hex

i have a form with two text fields, "from" and "to."

when i enter values such as "100000" and "10000F" and do a for loop, it always comes out like:

0 100001 100002 100003 100004 100005 100006 100007 100008 100009 10000a 10000b 10000c 10000d 10000e 10000f

if i plug in the range for the loop manually, i get:

100000 100001 100002 100003 100004 100005 100006 100007 100008 100009 10000a 10000b 10000c 10000d 10000e 10000f

using:

```
for ($i = '0x'.$_POST['from']; $i <= '0x'.$_POST['to']; $i++) { print dechex($i)."\n"; }
```

versus:

```
for ($i = 0x100000; $i <= 0x10000F; $i++) { print dechex($i)."\n"; }
```

if anyone knows what i am doing wrong here, please let me know.

i have also tried tried adding the "0x" to the numbers via the form with the same results.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `$i++` is converting `$i` to a number, this doesn't run until after the first loop.  Apparently `dechex` doesn't try to interpret strings as numbers and just barfs.

To force conversion, prefix the string expression with a `+`:

```
for ($i = +('0x'.$_POST['from']); $i <= '0x'.$_POST['to']; $i++) {
    print dechex($i)."\n";
}
```

Tested and working on PHP 5.2.6.

(Note that casting does not work!  `(int)('0x100000')` returns `0`.)

Comment: amazingly, cdhowie's solution was the only one that worked. the others kept converting back into base 10. they should've been base 10 to begin with :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) to convert a hex string to a number. [`dechex()`](http://php.net/dechex) will take the number and turn it back into a hex string:

```
$from = intval('100001', 16);
$to = intval('10000f', 16);

for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
  print dechex($i) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is what I'd do.  100x more readable than doing inline string-conversions on a concat'ed form post param.

Answer (score 0):

'0x'.$_POST['from']; is a string $i = 0x100000 is a number

Your first iteration will cast the string value to a number using standard PHP casting (as an integer value to the first non-numeric character, which is the 'x' giving a start value of 0)

Comment: @cambraca - it does, but by a very simplistic casting mechanism... it doesn't use intelligence to say "oh! you mean a hex value", it just looks for initial digit characters, and converts up to the first non-digit... defaulting to 0 if there are no leading digits

Comment: Wrong. See my answer. (And test it, of course, if you don't believe me.)

Comment: Seems like a bug in php, that it does it this way in `dechex` and then some other way with `++`, no?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your hex string to an actual integer first. Something like [this function does](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php#97172).

Otherwise, PHP will handle it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

`for ($i = intval('0x'.$_POST['from'], 0); $i <= intval('0x'.$_POST['to'], 0); $i++) { print dechex($i)."\n"; }`